# tensor product and einsum in numpy

Tags: tensor-products, python

I am trying to understand the `einsum` function in NumPy. In this [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), the last example,

```
>>> a = np.arange(60.).reshape(3,4,5)
>>> b = np.arange(24.).reshape(4,3,2)
>>> np.einsum('ijk,jil->kl', a, b)
array([[ 4400.,  4730.],
       [ 4532.,  4874.],
       [ 4664.,  5018.],
       [ 4796.,  5162.],
       [ 4928.,  5306.]])
>>> np.einsum(a, [0,1,2], b, [1,0,3], [2,3])
array([[ 4400.,  4730.],
       [ 4532.,  4874.],
       [ 4664.,  5018.],
       [ 4796.,  5162.],
       [ 4928.,  5306.]])
>>> np.tensordot(a,b, axes=([1,0],[0,1]))
array([[ 4400.,  4730.],
       [ 4532.,  4874.],
       [ 4664.,  5018.],
       [ 4796.,  5162.],
       [ 4928.,  5306.]])
```

I don't understand what's going on with this `np.einsum('ijk,jil->kl', a, b)` function. Can someone express it in a more explicit way, something like $$\sum_{???}a_{ijk}b_{ijk}$$? I'm not familiar with tensor product so that also contributes to my struggle here.

I'm learning this to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15535954/1382745) of mine.

Comment: You will find a very good explanation by @ajcr, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum)

Answer (score 6):

The result is a new array c, with
$$
c_{kl} = \sum_{i,j} a_{ijk} b_{jil}
.
$$

Comment: Thanks! And I found `np.einsum('ijk,jil', a, b)` also gives the same result, without the `->kl` part.

Comment: The reason for this is that what comes after `->` is how the output is treated. As you sum along *repeated* indices $i$ and $j$, the output depends on $k$ and $l$, the default without the `->` is to keep it this way. If you want to sum over those indices as well (sum the final columns or rows), you can do it like this  `np.einsum('ijk,jil->k', a, b)`. If you want to sum columns and rows, you could do `np.einsum('ijk,jil->', a, b)`.

Comment: numpy.einsum hits superfast BLAS-like routines?